# Inexplicable possible automated event

Tags: chrome-for-android, malware, yahoo-mail

I'd like to understand the cause of this:

1. I put the smartphone on airplane mode
2. After some hours I turn off the airplane mode, and activate internet connection
3. Suddenly, after having lowered the notification panel, automatically it opens the PlayStore with a string in the search field, something like *toroepan°tyf* (I don't remember it exactly), and the advice that any matching item hasn't been found
4. After this I notice that in *recent apps* there's Yahoo mail (I didn't opened it before)
5. I touch Yahoo from *recent apos*, and inexplicably it appears that I have choiced to open an attachment (it seems as a gif), so I go back with the upper arrow, and
6. It is showed a mix of a chat conversation and of a forum message I wrote about one month ago on Chrome
7. Moreover these pieces of written things alternate with gifs (please look at the second screenshot below representing the internal content), other images, and even a private video of the Android gallery
8. And it is a mail I would be ready to send to chrome-distiller://(many alphanumeric characters) (please see the 1st screenshot below)

I googled and summarily I've understood what distiller refers to and means.

The question is how it has been possible the existence of that mixture of pieces of web pages (chat, message on Chrome), even gifs and images I've never used and a shred of chat I wrote on *Lichess* app (which, I suppose, uses Chrome for the chat feature) in the form of a Yahoo draft.

Is it known a similar effect? Has someone else experienced something analogue? Maybe is it an Android or Chrome bug? Perhaps something malicious acting in the background?

I really can't figure out the cause of it.

[image: the draft in the list]

[image: a piece of the internal content]